# How to draw a circle inside a triangle css

Tags: html, css, geometry, triangle

[image]

I am trying to put this circle in the center of the triangle. I set the class triangle to display flex but it didn't work. Please help me.

The code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 300px solid black;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the html code:

Comment: you can find the "Edit" button below your question, use it to update it with the code

Comment: What do you mean by the center of the triangle?

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest – non SVG – ways to achieve this is as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
.collage {
  /* using grid layout means we can easily
     position the elements in the same place
     without nesting them: */
  display: grid;
  /* effectively the same as:
       justify-content: center;
       align-contents: center;
     to place the items in the center along
     the block and inline axes: */
  place-items: center;
}

.triangle {
  /* allows us to set the aspect-ratio, which causes
     the browser to compute one axis of the element
     based on the value we specify for 'other' axis;
     here we specify a height of 300px, so the browser
     calculates the other axis to 600px, making the
     triangle-shape twice as wide as its height: */
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  background-color: #000;
  /* using clip-path, with the CSS polygon() function,
     to specify a list of coordinates outside of which
     the element is clipped, instead of using the
     border hack to create a triangle: */
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  /* positions the element in the first grid-row
     and first grid-column: */
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  /* a shorthand for an aspect-ratio of: 1 / 1,
     which causes the browser to calculate the
     unknown axis to be same length as the
     specified axis (again, the height): */
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: #00f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  height: 210px;
  /* to place the element higher in the visual
     stack, 'closer' to the viewer: */
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="collage">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aoub9f65/).

Of course, if you're prepared to use SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="600" xml:space="preserve">
  <!-- this element is the background upon which
       the triangle and circle appear: -->
  <rect id="background"
        <!-- we fill the shape with black, the 'fill'
             being the 'background-color' -->
        style="fill: #fff;"
        <!-- these attributes determine the placement of
             the element, the x and y coordinates
             of the upper-left corner: -->
        x="-300" y="-300"
        <!-- determines the width and height: -->
        width="600" height="600"
        <!-- moves the element across the SVG, in the
             x and y axes: -->
        transform="translate(300 300)" />
  <path id="triangle"
        style="fill: #000;"
        <!-- this is the path of the triangle, the enclosed
             space being the filled portion: -->
        d="M-37.43 32.41 0-32.41l37.43 64.82z"
        transform="matrix(7.36 0 0 4.99 300 300)" />
  <circle id="circle"
          style="fill: #00f;"
          <!-- we specify the radius of the <circle>: -->
          r="35"
          <!-- and move it within the SVG for positioning: -->
          transform="matrix(3.01 0 0 3.01 300 300)" />
</svg>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aoub9f65/1/).

SVG is a little complex to explain, so unfortunately I've largely abdicated from that responsibility and left a link – in the bibliography below – from which you (and others) can learn more about it.

It's also worth stating that my own knowledge of SVG is limited, and I tend to use a program to create them, such as InkScape (other programs are, of course, available) or an online generator, as I did here.

References:

- [`align-contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-contents).
- [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).
- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items).
- [`<SVG>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg).
- [SVG element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element).
- [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," CSS-Tricks.
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)," Mozilla Developer Network.
- "[SVG Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)," Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider one element to draw both shapes:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(17% 34% at 50% 60%, blue 98%,#000); /* 34 = 17*2 */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to set top, right, left, bottom for your circle class in css.
For example:

```
 .circle {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%) //optional
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  border-right: 300px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 300px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  right : 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```